# Debug-only members

Tags: c++

Is there a nice way of including certain members only in the debug build of a program?

I have an indexed data structure of which I use a large number of instances, which carry certain status flag in case some contents of the data structure have changed, but the index hasn't been updated.
The status flag are only used to check that all uses of the index call the `update` functionality in case the data has been changed, but for performance and storage reasons, since there are lots of instances and the data structure might be changed a lot before `update` is called, I would like to keep this data only for the debug build.

There are basically two types of operations on these flags:

- Setting/Resetting the flag
- `assert`ing that the flag is not set, i.e. certain parts of the index are still valid.

Are there any nicer ways of achieving this than sprinkling my code with `#ifndef NDEBUG` statements?

Note: In my special use case, the performance hit might not be that large, but I'm still looking for a general way to approach this, since there are probably much more complex use cases for the same idea.

Comment: How bout marking your class methods virtual and have a debug class derive from that?

Comment: @PasserBy That's an interesting approach, hadn't really thought about using inheritance for this. Will the compiler still be able to deduce that the methods never really have to be called virtually, thus eliminating the need for vtables?

Comment: @PasserBy I guessed so too! To increase the likelyhood of triggering all edge cases, it would be helpful to be able to check larger problem sizes as well, thus it would be great to not make the debug version unnecessarily slower (compared to the #ifndef solution)

Comment: You know what, I'm not sure about that idea, play with it, see if anything works

Comment: I have a `#define IF_DEBUG(a)`, which value is `a` in debug builds, and in release builds it's empty. Settings/resetting a flag can be done with this.

Comment: I guess you could define a `constexpr` from the value (or lack thereof) of `NDEBUG` and then do template specialisations based on that `constexpr`. This may or may not sum up to even more typing than the pure `#ifdef` method, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce amount of #ifdefing by providing a base class with debug facilities:

```
class
t_MyDebugHelper
{
#ifdef NDEBUG
   public: void
   Set_Something(int value)
   {
       (void) value; // not used
   }

   public: void
   Verify_Something(void)
   {}
#else
   private: ::std::string m_some_info;
   private: int           m_some_value;

   public: void
   Set_Something(int value)
   {
       m_some_value = value;
   }   

   public: void
   Verify_Something(void)
   {
       // implementation
   }
#endif
};

class
t_MyClass
:   public t_MyDebugHelper
{
    public: void
    SomeMethod(void)    
    {
        t_MyDebugHelper::Verify_Something();
        t_MyDebugHelper::Set_Something(42);
        ...
    }
};
```

This method does not allow you to get rid of ifdef completely, however it allows to avoid them in the main code logic. In Release build all the debug helper functions will result in noop and `t_MyDebugHelper` class won't increase target class size due to empty base class optimization. If debug helper needs an access to `t_MyClass` methods then a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) could be applied.